# Laravel возвращает 404-й код ошибки, если не прошла валидация

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу включить вывод ошибок валидации в Laravel 8?

Если данные, отправленные в запросе не проходят валидацию, то возвращается 404-я ошибка, без описания, какое правило было нарушено. Хотя в документации написано что это должно возвращаться, как я понимаю, по-умолчанию.

Вот простой пример валидации:

```
public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
    ]);

...
}
```

Вот такой ответ получаю, если валидация не пройдена:
[image: Вот такой ответ получаю, если валидация не пройдена]

Сервер, где этот код выполняется используется только как бэк. Фронт разрабатывается отдельно (Это я к тому, что в мануалах пишется что ошибки список ошибок могу получить в `$errors`. Этот массив в моей реализации получить не получается, ну или я просто не знаю как это сделать)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нет, Вам пришла именно ошибка 404: не найден путь. пропишите команду `php artisan route:clear` и попробуйте снова. Или проверьте свой роут на ошибки. И да, проверять валидацию в контроллере как минимум некрасиво, используйте реквесры (`php artisan make:request Название_реквеста`)

Comment: Извините, но я же знаю что роут правильный. Если я в json "name2" заменю на "name", то всё будет работать корректно. Спасибо за рекомендацию по валидации, но мой вопрос был не в этом. На всякий случай проверил вашу теорию, но нет, ничего нового, увы, не вышло.

Answer (score 0):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return throw new CustomException('Вы не прошли валидацию');
}
```

..//
Это имел ввиду?

Comment: Такой вариант может сработать, но я говорю не совсем об этом. Но в моём случае после `$request->validate([` вообще ничего не обрабатывается. То есть на если валидация не прошла, то код дальше не выполняется